# How to trigger a client event from another client in meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

I have one client app for a tablet and one for a notebook. Those apps are located in the client folder: "tablet" and "monitor" respectively. My question is, is it possible to trigger an event from the tablet app to the notebook app? Because I want to switch through a pagination synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern for this in Meteor would be to save or update a document in a *collection* that is subscribed to by both clients and then have the clients react to that new or updated value.

For example:

lib:

```
SharedState = new Mongo.Collection('sharedstate');
```

server:

```
Meteor.publish('shared',function(){
  return SharedState.find({ userId: this.userId });
});
```

client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('shared');
```

in your client that is creating the event:

```
SharedState.upsert(
  { userId: Meteor.userId() },
  { userId: Meteor.userId(), state: "foo" }
);
```

Then in your client that is looking for the event use a [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html) (or alternatively, [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges)) to see that the shared state has changed:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  let state = SharedState.findOne({ userId: Meteor.userId() });
  if ( state === "foo" ){
    ... do your thing
  }
});
```

Here I'm assuming that your app running on your tablet and notebook are being used by the same *user* - hence the key for the shared state is the `userId`. If OTOH you were sharing state across a *classroom* (one teacher, several students), then you might use something like `classroomId` instead.

Comment: thank you very much. this will help me to solve the problem :)